# Redirecting all request to the root directory somewhere else?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Alright, so I've downloaded a CMS for a server I'm setting up and I have some difficulty with the path the files are on.

I have put the CMS in a subdirectory on my server as the root directory is already being used by another CMS. However, the CMS repeatedly uses "/" in the code to link to their files. For example, an image is found using this code:

```
<img src="/images/banner.png" />
```

As you know this will not work, because the link above redirects the request to the images folder in the root of the server, not the subdirectory. The CMS also came with a ".htaccess" file, so I immediately thought that I could redirect all requests made using the "/" character to the subdirectory on the server. This is the original ".htaccess" file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php(|/)$ content/.php
RewriteRule ^error.php(|/)$ content/error.php
RewriteRule ^housekeeping(|/)$ housekeeping/index.php
RewriteRule ^(|/)$ content/$1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ content/$1.php
RewriteRule ^rd/([^/]+)(|/)$ /rd.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^quickregister/start(|/)$ /register/start.php
RewriteRule ^quickregister/step2(|/)$ /register/step2.php
RewriteRule ^quickregister/step3(|/)$ /register/complete.php

RewriteRule ^community/online(|/)$ content/online.php
RewriteRule ^community/vip(|/)$ content/vip.php
RewriteRule ^credits/goldvip(|/)$ content/goldvip.php

RewriteRule ^home/(..*)$ content/home.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^articles/(..*)$ content/articles.php?story=$1

ErrorDocument 403 /content/error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /content/error.php
```

I thought that by adding

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /subdirectory/
```

the requests to "/" would be redirected, but to no avail. I have checked the apache configuration and it seems that overwriting the config using htaccess files is enabled, so if anyone is able to help me out I'd be very happy.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I came real close to a solution. I inserted this code just below "RewriteEngine on":

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /private_servers/strebbohotel/$2
```

This returned the following error page when visiting the url "http://mysite.com/private_servers/strebbohotel/content/.php":
Not Found

The requested URL /private_servers/strebbohotel/.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

As you can see, it skips the "content" subdirectory for some reason. I believe it has something to do with the other lines of the .htaccess file but I can't figure out which ones. It also could be that I need a more complex regex, but I'm not particularly good with it so if someone could help me further I'd be thankful.

Comment: Please accept answers for your previous questions.  You have four questions which were answered over six months ago, but you have not selected an answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not know you could accept answers. I'll get on it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the .htaccess file on yout root directory - and that will mess with the other CMS. The only solution that comes to my mind is to use combination of RewriteCond's:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} my_better_cms_url_regex
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /subdirectory/%{REQUEST_URI}
```

That should do the trick. If you want to customize it, refer to [this cheatsheet](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html) (or simmilar). But be aware, that .htaccess in root directory is checked against ALL requests made to your subdir cms - therefore the need for second condition.

Comment: The code looks like it should work, however when I've modified it and inserted it into my htaccess file, I receive an internal server error.

Comment: I edited my main post with new code, which I partially got from yours. I've almost solved it but I've got a strange problem now. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Your code matches two sections - one which contains 'any characters (including slashes)', then a slash, and then another 'anything'. Try using this:
RewriteRule ^([\/]*)/(.*)$ /private_servers/strebbohotel/$2
to remove only the first element of request (if that's what you're trying to acomplish?)

Answer (score 1):

The .htaccess file in your CMS subdirectory would have no effect on requests made against the server root directory.  You would need to add an .htaccess there.

Even then though, I don't know how you would differentiate requests from the CMS (like the image request in your example) from those intended for the application in the web root.

Does your CMS not have any configuration setting that allow you to specify a path the the files other than the web root?

Comment: Oh okay, my understanding of htaccess files was that they only affected the directory they're in and their subdirectories. And to answer your question, the CMS is kind of a quickly written piece of code, so it doesn't have a configuration page or file. The links in the files are all static and replacing them all would be a real pain.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use:

```
RewriteBase /another_root_dir/
```

in the beginning of your .htaccess file